# Sending data to thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I am having two classes one main class and another server class. I am calling run method in server class as a seperate thread from main class. I need to pass values from main class to server class periodically.

I tried using std::atomic but the value in the thread is not getting changed.

Am I doing something wrong below? Any help or advice is highly appreciated. THanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "server.h"
#include "atomic"

using namespace std;
std::atomic<int> clientSignal(-1);
void foo();

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    server* board;

    board = new server();
    thread serverThread(&server::run,*board,std::ref(clientSignal));
    serverThread.join();
    foo(); // the value of clientSignal is changed from within main class //based on input from sensors. 
    return 0;
}

void foo(){
    clientSignal = 8;
}
```

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H


class server
{
public:
    server();
    ~server();
    void run(std::atomic<int> &clientSignal);
private:
    std::atomic<int> *clientFlag;

};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

server.cpp

```
#include "server.h"

server::server()
{
}

server::~server()
{
}

void server::run(std::atomic<int> &clientSignal) {
    clientFlag = &clientSignal;

    cout << *clientFlag;

    ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to read more what the [`join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) function does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks it solved the issue.